# CDI Inject EntityManagers by field name with @Produces

Tags: java, ejb, cdi, entitymanager

I am implementing a Java EE application deployed to Wildfly 8.2.0. There are multiple EntityManagers, which I want to inject by field name. For that I created a producer method with @Produces that gets field name from the InjectionPoint.

```
public class Resources {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "primary")
    private EntityManager primaryEm;

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "secondary")
    private EntityManager secondaryEm;

    @Produces
    public EntityManager getEntityManager(InjectionPoint injectionPoint)
        throws Exception {
        Field field = getClass().getDeclaredField(
               injectionPoint.getMember().getName());

        return (EntityManager) field.get(this);
    }
}
```

Then I can simply inject the EntityManager with the proper field name:

```
@Inject
private EntityManager primaryEm;
```

This solution works so far, but is there another, more elegant way in CDI to implement this "inject by field name" feature?

Answer (score 1):

I think your solution is prettiest as possible. Or maybe you could describe in details what does it mean for you elegance?

Comment: I am happy to read that. Well, I was wondering if there is a possibility to solve this problem without that producer method including reflection.